# Progress indication on multiple looped ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a requirement of using multiple ajax requests to hit an API multiple times. 
How can I set a progress indication for these ajax. My Progress indication should complete once all the requests complete and page is ready.
I have tried ajaxStart() and ajaxComplete() functions, but it is working fine only if the ajax are not looped inside for(;;).

Below is my code

```
for(var j=0; j<datesForcomputation.length; j++ ) {
    url = " some/url";
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        cache: true,
        success: function(response){
            // success block

        },error: function(response){
            //error block
            console.log("Errored for"+ url + "-" +response);
        }
    });
}
```

Any help? Or even any alternative approach? 
Thanks!

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: 3 minutes to render your page? No offence but I wouldn't like to be a user of your application...a lot of waiting

Comment: I have tried $(document).ajaxStart() and $(document).ajaxComplete(), ajax xhr nothing is working working. But the console.log inside ajaxStart is working. Any UI related updation or addition is reflecting only after all ajax is completed. Even hide and show of an element is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Progress indication ? May be you want user to know what's going on until your data from Ajax is loaded . Use an Ajax loader image that should be visible just before Ajax call is fired , and then hide it using JQuery .But 3 minutes ? If you're sure about that Ajax takes exactly 3 minutes to complete, just display a formal message that request is under process, and expect changes after 3 min . No user will be interested in monitoring progress of a process that takes 3 minutes to render the changes on the user interface . is that it ?

Comment: the ajaxStart and Complete functions works fine only if the requests are not looped in for(;;)